# Typeface.js not rendering in Safari or opera?

Tags: typeface.js

Typeface.js not rendering in Safari or opera? i have uploaded files and tested but it is not working plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Safari 2+ should be supported according to [their page](http://typeface.neocracy.org/), but not Opera.

Comment: Safari 3.2.2 is also not supporting. you have any better way to use custom fonts in website ?